# in python (plt.table set rowColours in first row)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I always get an error when I want to make the first row of my table color.I want to create a table and highlight the first row in color. Is there any other way to shape that? 
Edit here is my complete code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import table


#first_page
DATA_FILE = "C:/test/corr.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel("C:/test/corr.xlsx")
s = df.iloc[0:15, 0:10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 1))
plt.suptitle("1.Excel-Daten", fontsize =15)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  
ax.set_frame_on(False)  
tabla = table(ax, s, colWidths=[0.30]*len(df.columns), rowColours='r', 
colColours = 'r')
tabla.auto_set_font_size(False) 
tabla.set_fontsize(15)

tabla.scale(1.5,1.5)
plt.show
```

**My error is:**

> runfile('C:/Users/ucarm.lokal/.spyder-py3/untitled17.py', 
>       wdir='C:/Users/ucarm.lokal/.spyder-py3')
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/ucarm.lokal/.spyder-py3/untitled17.py', 
>       wdir='C:/Users/ucarm.lokal/.spyder-py3')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 
>       705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 
>       102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/ucarm.lokal/.spyder-py3/untitled17.py", line 25, in 
>       tabla = table(ax, s, colWidths=[0.30]*len(df.columns), rowColours='r', 
>       colColours = 'r')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_tools.py", line 65, in 
>       table
>       colLabels=colLabels, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\table.py", line 652, in table
>       text=colLabels[col], facecolor=colColours[col],
>
> ```
> IndexError: string index out of range
> ```

Comment: please show (a sample of) your data (e.g. df.head() for the start, and just to be complete: as text please, no screenshot...). which line does throw the error message? which imports did you prepend?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the extra information, and provide a [mcve] of the issue that other people can run.